# strcpy doesn't work on the same size arrays

Tags: c++, error-handling, strcpy

When I try to assign value of one string to other using `strcpy` runtime error occurs. Below the code:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{ 
  char str[5];
  char str2[5];//if set size of str2 equal to 6, no error occurs

  str[0] = 'a';
  str[1] = 'b';
  str[2] = 'c';
  str[3] = 'd';
  str[4] = 'e';

  cout<<sizeof(str)<<endl;
  cout<<str[0]<<endl;
  cout<<str[1]<<endl;
  cout<<str[2]<<endl;
  cout<<str[3]<<endl;
  cout<<str[4]<<endl;

  strcpy(str2,str);

  cout<<sizeof(str2)<<endl;
  cout<<str2[0]<<endl;
  cout<<str2[1]<<endl;
  cout<<str2[2]<<endl;
  cout<<str2[3]<<endl;
  cout<<str2[4]<<endl;

  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

Error is:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted
```

If I set the size of str2 equal to 6 or more program works well. 
What is a problem here?

Comment: Even with str2[6], str2[7] gives error. Barmar answer is correct.

Comment: terminate the strings, or if they aren't strings, use `memcpy`

Comment: You are correct. strcpy does NOT work on arrays. What is your question

Answer (score 7):

`strcpy` operates on zero-terminated strings. Your char arrays don't have terminating zero bytes.

If it's working when you declare the arrays as `[6]` it's just by accident.

Answer (score 5):

Function [`strcpy();`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) expects nul `\0` terminated string. `str[]` is not nul `\0` terminated.

Because you are printing array char by char in your code, you can rectify code as suggested by @[Karoly Horvath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650405/karoly-horvath) using memcpy instead of strcpy.

[void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t count );](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy)

```
memcpy(str2, str, sizeof(str));
```

Comment: What changements can I do so that program works well, but both str and str have the same size?

Comment: terminate the strings, or if they aren't strings, use `memcpy`

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov sorry before I could write answer my Internet filed. :( read other answer

Comment: @NurlanKenzhebekov note you have undefined behavior in your code

Answer (score 3):

It is very risky to use string operations without forming null-terminated strings.

Here, strcpy() expects a null terminated string to be copied to a string which also has to be null terminated.

Therefore you must use:

```
  char str[6];
  char str2[6];

  str[0] = 'a';
  str[1] = 'b';
  str[2] = 'c';
  str[3] = 'd';
  str[4] = 'e';
  str[5] = '\0';
  strcpy(str2,str);
```

Comment: Or `char str[] = "abcde";`. `str` will have 6 elements, including the terminating `\0`.